# How to interrupt parent touch event

Tags: android, android-listview, parallax, ontouchlistener, android-viewgroup

I am writing an custom ViewGroup and following [neevek](http://neevek.net/posts/2013/10/13/implementing-onInterceptTouchEvent-and-onTouchEvent-for-ViewGroup.html) to get touch interruption between parent and Child(ListView). Here Custom ViewGroup help to uplift ListView.

**What I need:** So once ListView uplift at top, I want to start scroll it for which I need to interrupt ParentTouch event and allow control back to child.

I tried with `ListView.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(flag);` but it's not working.

Any suggestion here !

Answer (score 0):

Return `true` for you event that you don't need to pass to the parent. if you return `true` the event will be consumed by the listener and will not be passed to the parent.

Comment: yes..but if keep on drag parent then child.touch never get called.